# How to use CMake to force linkage of shared library

Tags: cmake

It seems that CMake will strip unnecessary link dependencies by default when building an executable.

Unfortunately, I need to force a certain shared library to be linked so that it gets loaded during initialization time.

Is there anyway to do this nicely?

I have the following vicious hack:

```
target_link_options (${target} PRIVATE -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,/usr/lib/libxrt_hwemu.so.2.13.12 -Wl,--as-needed)
```

Comment: CMake can't know if the dependency is necessary or not so it can't strip anything. That's your linker's deeds not CMake's. And as such you need to convince the linker not CMake which you did successfully, it seems like.

Comment: @ixSci I agree with your statements. The trouble with this hack is I had to remove the library from target_link_dependencies(), and put it in target_link_options(). This is not the right thing to do as CMake doesn’t even know the library target is a dependency. I think I need to investigate more as to why the linker was stripping unused dependencies.